# Q: How to put values in keys in a Text file into order from biggest - smallest? (python 2.7.11)

Tags: python

**Text file explained:**

```
Joe,Bloggs,J.bloggs@anemailaddress.com,01269512355, 1  , 20, 0, 0, 0
fname, lname, email, number, ..., number i want to order ^, ...,...,..
```

**Text file:**

```
Joe,Bloggs,J.bloggs@anemailaddress.com,01269512355, 1,20, 0, 0, 0
Sarah,Brown,S.brown@anemailaddress.com,01866522555, 1,25, 0, 0, 0
Andrew,Smith,A.smith@anemailaddress.com,01899512785, 1,30, 0, 0, 0
Ray,Charles,R.charles@anemailaddress.com,01268712321, 1,3, 0, 0, 0
Kevin,White,K.white@anemailaddress.com,01579122345, 1,0, 5, 0, 0
Samantha,Collins,S.collins@anemailaddress.com,04269916257, 1,0, 0, 0, 0
```

objective: I want to be able to put the keys in order based on the results of value[5]. This is so it is easier to change value[4] as i require the top 2 scoring and lowest 2 scoring keys to have their value[4] changed. As so, highest 2 value[4] - 1, lowest score value[4] + 1.

**Text file after code has run:**

```
Andrew,Smith,A.smith@anemailaddress.com,01899512785, 0,30, 0, 0, 0
Sarah,Brown,S.brown@anemailaddress.com,01866522555, 0,25, 0, 0, 0
Joe,Bloggs,J.bloggs@anemailaddress.com,01269512355, 1,20, 0, 0, 0
Kevin,White,K.white@anemailaddress.com,01579122345, 1,5, 0, 0, 0
Ray,Charles,R.charles@anemailaddress.com,01268712321, 2,3, 0, 0, 0
Samantha,Collins,S.collins@anemailaddress.com,04269916257, 2,0, 0, 0, 0
```

**Code i have so far:**

```
f = open("players.txt", "r"
lines = []
for line in f.readlines():
        line = [x.strip() for x in line.split(',')]
        line[4] = int(line[4])
        line[5] = int(line[5])
        lines.append(line)
f.close()

values = sorted(list(set([l[4] for l in lines])),reverse=True)
max_values = (values[0], values[1])

for line in lines:
        if line[5] in max_values:
                line[4] += 1
        else:
                line[4] -= 1

with open("players.txt", "w") as f:
            for line in lines:
                line = [str(x) for x in line]
                f.write(', '.join(line) + '\n')
```

This is my code and it is pretty complicated. It doesn't seem to work the way i want because it produces this error.

```
max_values = (values[0], values[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Feel free to completely re-write my code to make it better. Im new to coding and so don't yet have the knowledge to do most things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root problem is that all of your l[4] values are **1**.  In your **sorted** statement, I think you want l[5], no?

In the given code, all the values are 1.  When you make a set from those, you have only a single element left.  You make a list from the set, sort that, and the resulting list has only one element.  Thus, values[1] is out of range.

Just change that line to properly get your sort key.  Note the subscript of **5**, not **4**.

```
values = sorted(list(set([l[5] for l in lines])),reverse=True)
```

---

Also, I think you're mis-handling the alteration for the minimum values.  Your code adds 1 for any key that isn't one of the top 2, but you said that you want to alter only the bottom two.  Try this:

```
max_values = (values[0], values[1])
min_values = (values[-1], values[-2])

for line in lines:
        if line[5] in min_values:
                line[4] += 1
        elif line[5] in max_values:
                line[4] -= 1
```

Comment: I think you miss understand. I want the keys to be arranged in ascending order from biggest to smallest from value[5]. I then want the top 2 in that list and the bottom 2 to have their value[4] changed. @Prune

Comment: I understand.  However, your keys are at **values[5]**.  Your **sorted** statement gathers the keys from **values[4]**.

Comment: thank you for that correction. Now it works nicely :)

Comment: Glad to be of help.  I do recommend that you look at **wtpoo**'s answer, too: **itemgetter** is a very useful Python tool, and I think you can build a more elegant program with it.  I think you'll want to change the **4** to a **5** in his suggested code, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the lines based on certain param with operator.itemgetter

```
 from operator import itemgetter
 values = sorted(lines, key=itemgetter(4), reverse=True)
```

You can read all the lines in a list, which you are already doing.

Then iterate all the lines in a list to update value[4] or value[5]

Then you can use above code to sort the updated list.

Iterate over the list and write it to file.